# SAP Business One SDK - Capture and override PDF Export Button Event

Tags: pdf, sapb1

There is a limitation with the PDF export button when using Print Sequences in SAP 9.0 (http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1711169).

I have a client who would like to avoid the use of a PDF generator tool like Bullzip and retain the standard functionality. The first approach which comes to mind is overriding the PDF export button click event from the Toolbar menu using the UI-API, but I've researched a bit and can't find if this is possible or not.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Does it trigger as a menu event or some other event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the PDF export button in the tool bar and the File > Export PDF option on the menu trigger a Menu Event under the Menu ID "7176".

Comment: Are you able to figure out how to export a document to PDF through SDK, and in particular how to provide the file name programmatically? If yes, can you post a sample code here. Thanks.

Comment: @AllSolutions Sorry, it's been 4+ years since I worked on this, so I can't give any details. However, I do recall being able to programmatically override the Export PDF functionality with the UI-API and save the PDF. There should be tutorials out there in the SAP Docs on how to do this.